# Where should I place the constant?

Tags: python, performance, constants

The following bit of code requires a `string.maketrans` table that is only used inside a single function.

I have written three versions of the program that place the table at different locations in the code. The differing placement of the table results in quite varying performance in the creation of `DNA` instances and calls to the `to_rna` method.

So, which one of these variants is preferable? Or is there even a different, better solution?

Version 1:

```
from string import maketrans


DNA_RNA_TRANSLATION_TABLE = maketrans('GCTA', 'CGAU')


class DNA(object):
    """Represent a strand of DNA."""

    def __init__(self, dna_string):
        self.dna_string = dna_string

    def to_rna(self):
        """Return the RNA complement of the DNA strand."""
        return self.dna_string.translate(DNA_RNA_TRANSLATION_TABLE)
```

Version 2:

```
from string import maketrans


class DNA(object):
    """Represent a strand of DNA."""

    __rna_translation_table = maketrans('GCTA', 'CGAU')

    def __init__(self, dna_string):
        self.dna_string = dna_string

    def to_rna(self):
        """Return the RNA complement of the DNA strand."""
        return self.dna_string.translate(self.__rna_translation_table)
```

Version 3:

```
from string import maketrans


class DNA(object):
    """Represent a strand of DNA."""

    def __init__(self, dna_string):
        self.dna_string = dna_string

    def to_rna(self):
        """Return the RNA complement of the DNA strand."""
        translation_table = maketrans('GCTA', 'CGAU')
        return self.dna_string.translate(translation_table)
```

Comment: As it stands, this post isn't asking for code to be reviewed, and could be closed as primarily opinion-based. You could remove versions 2 and 3, and ask for version 1 to be peer reviewed, mentioning your concern with the placement of `maketrans`.

Comment: @Mat'sMug: I get your point. I've added a sentence to make clear that performance, too, is an important aspect in this problem. Yet I don't quite see how the provision of three basic options would make a review of the problem impossible?

Comment: @simon CodeReview is (often) about applying best practices to code, not deciding what those best practices are (which is on topic on [programmers.se]. It is a subtle, but important difference

Answer (score 6):

I will answer your question in an unexpected way : the better solution is, as far as I can tell, much more straightforward than what you are doing.

Indeed, [you don't need a class](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o9pEzgHorH0) : your class has an `__init__` and a single method `to_rna`, it might as well be a single function.

```
from string import maketrans

def dna_to_rna(dna_string):
    """Return the RNA complement of the DNA strand."""
    return dna_string.translate(maketrans('GCTA', 'CGAU'))
```

I think see this the neatest solution. Then if on only want to create the table only once for performance reason, you can put it a variable outside the function but it's probably not needed.

Comment: And if performance is the concern, consider caching the maketrans as a default value for an extra parameter to the function. That makes it both a local variable (fast) and customizable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Josay! You're absolutely right that using a class here is absolutely unnecessary. The only reason I did it anyway was because it was specified in the test for the exercise that I wrote this code for.

Comment: Your "you don't need a class" link was both enlightening and amusing - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## Make the table local

See Michael Urman's comment on [Josay's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44241/37331). For both optimisation and readability it is beneficial to make `translation_table` local to the `to_rna` object method. In your version 1 it is a global variable, in your version 2 it is a class attribute, and in your version 3 it is a local variable but it is created from scratch each time the function is called. Global variables take longer to look up than class attributes, which take longer to look up than local variables. In this particular case I would expect the speed up due to using a local variable to be small since considerably more time will be taken up using the table than initially looking up the variable that holds it (except for very short DNA strands...).

What will make a big difference is not having to recreate the table every time you call the method. For this reason I expect you are currently seeing approaches 1 and 2 running faster than approach 3. However, approach 3 keeps the definition of the table within the method, so it can easily be seen by anyone looking at that method, and doesn't need to be looked at by anyone not focussed on that method. This makes it more readable for everyone involved.

In this case it can be both readable and fast. You can keep the table definition within the method **and** ensure it is only created once (when the method is first defined) by making it an extra parameter with a default value, as Michael suggests.

Since the table is intended to be set up once and never changed, you may also want to call it `TRANSLATION_TABLE` in all upper case, which is the convention for constants in Python.

## Example object method

```
def to_rna(self, TRANSLATION_TABLE=maketrans('GCTA', 'CGAU')):
    """Return the RNA complement of the DNA strand."""
    return self.dna_string.translate(TRANSLATION_TABLE)
```

In general this also makes it customisable (you can feed in a different table if you ever want to use the same method for a different type of translation). Even if the DNA to RNA translation is all you are likely to use this method for, this approach is still worthwhile for the combination of readability and speed. In this case the upper case table name makes it clear to other programmers that you do not expect the function to be customised in practice.

This approach will work equally well whether you take [Josay's advice](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44241/37331) of not using a class, or end up adding extra features and needing a class after all.

## Example function without a class

```
def dna_to_rna(dna_string, TRANSLATION_TABLE=maketrans('GCTA', 'CGAU')):
    """Return the RNA complement of the DNA strand."""
    return dna_string.translate(TRANSLATION_TABLE)
```

---

## EDIT: The numbers: comparing timings

As Gareth Rees comments below, this explanation isn't reliable without measurement. So I ran the 4 versions and the timings were not quite what I expected...

Note that I'm using Python 3, so instead of `from string import maketrans` I'm just using `str.maketrans`. These timings should be measured again if you are using Python 2.

First I ran each of the 4 versions (1 to 3 from the question, plus my version), creating an object of the class and calling `to_rna` 100,000,000 times. I used a null string to create the object as it is only the lookup of the table constant I was interested in measuring. As expected, with the default local parameter giving minimum lookup overhead, version 4 is the fastest for calling **once the object is created**.

```
File        to_rna  cumulative  total running time
Version1    69.741  84.363      154.089
Version2    78.881  159.077     159.077
Version3    136.938 262.078     366.644
Version4    64.813  79.246      153.369
```

The table shows results for the following code added to each class definition file:

```
def lots_of_calls():
    test = DNA('')
    for i in range(100000000):
        unused = test.to_rna()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lots_of_calls()
```

Timings were measured from the command line:

```
python -m cProfile version1.py
```

All times are in seconds.

Contrary to my expectations, the global constant in version 1 was significantly faster than the class attribute in version 2. I don't have a reason for this, which just goes to show how important it is to measure rather than guess...

Where I expected versions 1 and 2 to be the fastest was when creating a new object each time the translation is required, since the global constant and class attribute only need to be created once, and simply added by reference to each new object.  Both versions 3 and 4 require constructing the table from scratch for each new object (or so I had presumed), so I expected them to be considerably slower in this case.

I ran each of the 4 versions again, creating an object and calling `to_rna`, and repeating to create a new object 100,000,000 times, calling its `to_rna` method each time. To my surprise the time taken to run  `__init__` was similar for all 4 versions, which meant that with its faster `to_rna` call, version 4 was still significantly faster than the others - the opposite of what I had expected.

```
File        init class  to_rna  cumulative to_rna   total running time
Version1    58.671      81.608  98.953              390.794
Version2    60.628      87.671  104.809             394.145
Version3    60.452      147.612 284.876             616.561
Version4    59.039      74.342  91.624              383.731
```

The table shows results for the following code:

```
def lots_of_calls():
    for i in range(100000000):
        test = DNA('')
        unused = test.to_rna()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lots_of_calls()
```

So in both cases, version 1 is the fastest of the original 3 versions. However, version 4 is the fastest overall **even when creating an object just for a single call**.

I don't know the reason for this.  My best guess would be that the table for the default parameter is created once when the class is defined, and then just added as a reference in each new object that is created (rather than a new default table being created for each new object).

If this is the case, it doesn't cause any conflict between objects. I created an object, overrode its table by calling `to_rna` with a table instead of zero arguments, and then called it again with zero arguments. The default table was used, so any override applies only to that particular call and that particular object instance.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! One thing I didn't understand is why the table is an object attribute in Version 3. If it's created inside the method, shouldn't it be a local variable?

Comment: Thanks @simon you are correct - I have reworded my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Speculation about timing is unsatisfying. Numbers, please!

Comment: @Gareth I agree. Thanks for raising this. Ideally I should time local/object/class/global variable look up. I believe Python searches the namespaces in [that order](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces) so it finds them sooner the earlier they come in that ordering. However, I don't know if checking whether a parameter with a default has received an argument adds on enough time to cancel that out, so I accept that I'm not comparing like for like.

Comment: I still recommend using the parameter with a default because it is readable (keeps the description of the table with the only function that uses it). I don't feel the need to test that a default is quicker than creating the table from scratch in function each call, but I should make time to compare the timings for the global and class attribute cases.

Comment: @GarethRees I've added in some timings now, and they've highlighted my misconceptions. This will make me far less likely to guess in future, so thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! There's really no substitute for measurement. (You might want to look at the [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module, which you could use to simplify your timing code.)